# python: Name Error:name 'data_x' is not defined

Tags: abaqus

I am doing my project on incremental deep drawing using ABAQUS.
I am trying to import a text file of loop program into abaqus script so that there is no need of entering amplitude values manually.

But I am getting an error when trying to import the data using the following code

```
f = open('data_x', 'r')
values=f.read()
values=f.readline()
```

Error:

> data_x is not defined

Comment: Please paste exact error message and check if file 'data_x' exists.

Comment: is it data_x.txt or data_x.dat the actual name of the file?

Comment: the exact error message is NameError: name 'data_x' is not defined

Comment: yes it is data_x.txt file

Comment: we have saved data_x as .txt file and then just placed it in the program it is then showing the above stated error i don't know the exact syntax of defining the data_x in the real programme can you kindly help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Error `NameError: name 'data_x' is not defined` points that you are using `data_x` as a name in your code, not as a string (with quotes).

This means that in your code, you probably have something like

```
f = open(data_x)
```

Python is trying to figure out which value is associated with `data_x`, which is a Python name, not a string. Since it's not defined before getting to that line, you are getting an error.

If you want to store the name of a file and then open a file, write

```
data_x = 'data_x.txt'
f = open(data_x)
```

You could also directly write

```
f = open('data_x.txt')
```

Whichever solution you adopt, make sure that a correct path to the file is passed to the function `open`, so that it could find the file.

Comment: thanks for the solution but now its giving an error TypeError: data; found string, expecting tuple can you help me with this

Comment: You might want to open a new question, unless it's really connected tightly to this one.

Comment: the exact code is   f = open('data_x.txt', 'r')
values=f.read() 
values=f.readline()  when calling data_x at some other point its showing above stated error like TypeError: data; found string, expecting tuple

Comment: You should show us the code at which the error is happening and some context around it to figure out the solution.